# Integration test solution for controlling Docker container lifecycle

Tags: docker, maven, testing, plugins, testcontainers

Right now I am using [maven-docker-plugin](https://dmp.fabric8.io/) for starting 3 containers and running multiple tests. I would like to be able to start 2 containers, and do some prerequisites and when running a specific test, only then to start the 3d container.

I went through the documentation of the plugin and understood that this is not possible. My thoughts right now are to use Testcontainers. Is there any other library or framework that can achieve this? Or should I use Testcontainers?